# multiple fade in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to fade in  first para when page loads and second one after 5sec 
when page loads. i have already made this two hidden in css?

```
    <p class="welcome">WELCOME &nbsp;    TO  &nbsp;  PAG</p>
    <p class="touch">"a land of passes"</p>

      <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000).removeclass('hidden');
              $('.touch').delay(5000),fadeIn(5000).removeclass('hidden');

           });

       </script>
```

Comment: Your example should work, you just need to fix the syntax error, use `.fadeIn(5000)` instead of `,fadeIn(5000)` (dot instead of comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire the second animation inside the complete callback of the first animation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000, function() {
    $('.touch').fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
  }).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000, function() {
    $('.touch').fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
  }).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.welcome,
.touch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="welcome">WELCOME &nbsp; TO &nbsp; PAG</p>
<p class="touch">"a land of passes"</p>
```

---

Alteranate method with yourown code, to make it work fix following typos in your code:

1. Use `delay(5000).fadeIn(5000)` instead of `delay(5000),fadeIn(5000)`, since comma doesn't works as you expected(dot is uaing for chaining).
2. Use `removeClass` instead of `removeclass`, the `C` should be capital.

Final code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
  $('.touch').delay(5000).fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
  $('.touch').delay(5000).fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.welcome,
.touch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="welcome">WELCOME &nbsp; TO &nbsp; PAG</p>
<p class="touch">"a land of passes"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.promise()`, `.then()`. Note, `.removeclass()` should be `.removeClass()`

```css
.welcome, .touch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.welcome').fadeIn(5000)
    .promise().then(function() {
      return $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    })
    .then(function() {
    $('.touch').delay(5000)
    .fadeIn(5000).removeClass('hidden');
    })

  });
</script>
<p class="welcome">WELCOME &nbsp; TO &nbsp; PAG</p>
<p class="touch">"a land of passes"</p>
```